# Best practice for creating paymentIntent and storing clientSecret with stripe

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments

I've been reading over the stripe API and it says to create a paymentIntent as soon as I know the total amount. I can use "useEffect" when the customer loads the checkout page and create a paymentIntent from there, but where should I store the clientSecret to retrieve this paymentIntent if the customer navigates away from checkout and then comes back? In the stripe documents, it says: *"You can use the client secret to complete the payment process with the amount specified on the PaymentIntent. Don’t log it, embed it in URLs, or expose it to anyone other than the customer. Make sure that you have TLS on any page that includes the client secret."* Is it safe to store the clientSecret in local storage or is there a better option?

When watching the official stripe videos it never mentioned anything about TLS so how do I go about ensuring that I have TLS on the page as well? (My backend is currently through the Next.js api routes)  *Edit: I just discovered that when hosting with vercel, they automatically configure SSL on the page for you.

The way I have my flow setup is that the customer will click one button that will first create a paymentIntent and then right after that use confirmCardPayment to confirm the paymentIntent. When reading the docs, it seems like this isn't the best way to have it set up.

Comment: Imagine you're on vacation and handed the keys to your flat in 20 story building to your friend to take care about your plants. Your friend decides to store your keys under your doormat for the remaining two weeks.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it safe to store the clientSecret in local storage or is there a better option?

You wouldn't want to store the client secret in a database. You would either (a) create a new Payment Intent and get a new client secret from it, or (b) store the Payment Intent ID and make an API call to retrieve the client secret with it when the customer navigates back to your payment page.

> The way I have my flow setup is that the customer will click one button that will first create a paymentIntent and then right after that use confirmCardPayment to confirm the paymentIntent. When reading the docs, it seems like this isn't the best way to have it set up.

This payment flow will work just fine and is recommended in the Stripe documentation (for example [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#web-create-intent))

[image]